# Creating Win32 events from c#

Tags: c#, events, interop

I'd like create a kernel(aka named events) from C#.

Do I have to interop services and wrap the native CreateEvent function or is there already  a .NET class that does the job?

The function that I need to run should be something like this: 
hEvent = CreateEvent ( NULL , false , false , "MyCSHARPEvent" );

This should notify all procs that probing forMyCSHARPEvent about the event.

If there is a need to wrap the function, how would I translate the SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES struct from C# to win32?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Take a look at the [EventWaitHandle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.eventwaithandle.aspx) class. It's supported from .Net 2.0 onwards and allows creation of named events. It also supports setting event security, depending on which constructor you use.

Answer (score 7):

If you still want to use interop, you can define the function like this:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
static extern IntPtr CreateEvent(IntPtr lpEventAttributes, bool bManualReset, bool bInitialState, string lpName);
```

and the struct like this(you may have to mess with the Pack attribute to make it fit):

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
struct SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES{
  public int length;
  public IntPtr securityDesc;
  public bool inherit;
}
```

Also, here's a [code example](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32.CreateEvent) of putting it all together.

Comment: Wow - I thought only the CF was that crippled (it still doesn't support named EventWaitHandles).

Comment: CF 3.5 now does support EventWaitHandles.

Comment: Why do so many people think that PInvoke is the .net solution to everything?

Comment: @Dan you realize you're responding to an answer that is over 4 years old, right?